# JavaScript: Fast parsing of yyyy-mm-dd into year, month, and day numbers

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

How can I parse *fast* a yyyy-mm-dd string (ie. "2010-10-14") into its year, month, and day numbers?

A function of the following form:

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var y, m, d;

    ...

    return {
      year: y,
      month: m,
      day: d
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can split it:

```
var split = str.split('-');

return {
    year: +split[0],
    month: +split[1],
    day: +split[2]
};
```

The `+` operator forces it to be converted to an integer, and is immune to the infamous octal issue.

Alternatively, you can use fixed portions of the strings:

```
return {
    year: +str.substr(0, 4),
    month: +str.substr(5, 2),
    day: +str.substr(8, 2)
};
```

Comment: So '2010-10-09' won't get clobbered by the `+` operator?

Comment: @Jimmy: Huh? I'm not doing that.

Comment: I mean, `+'09'` (the day in '2010-10-09') won't be octal?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the JavaScript split() method - lets you're split the string by the - character into an array. You could then easily take those values and turn it into an associative array..

```
return {
  year: result[0],
  month: result[1],
  day: result[2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

10 years later ,
If you want to extract Years from an array, this will help you:

jQuery:

```
    function splitDate(date) {
      newDate = [];
    
      $.map(date, function (item) {
        arr = item.split("-");
        newDate.push(arr[0]);
      });
    
      return newDate;
    }
```

Traditional way  :

```js
const splitDate = (date) => {
  const newDate = [];

  date.map(item => {
    let arr = item.split("-");
    newDate.push(arr[0]);
  });

  return newDate;
}

const dateArr = ['2013-22-22', '2016-22-22', '2015-22-22', '2014-22-22'];
const year = splitDate(dateArr);

console.log(year)
```