# Add days to date format yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

The question is simple, how can I add days to a date in YYYY-MM-DD format?

For example, increment a date given in this format: "2013-02-11" to "2013-02-12"?

Comment: Do you mean you have a string `'2013-02-11'` and you want to increase the day field by a certain number?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930862/add-30-days-to-date-mm-dd-yy. There are tons of similar questions if you look at the column on the right (`Related`).

Comment: Not the same format, but i will try replaying / with -

Comment: Yes, it's not the same format but it's easy to apply the solution to yours.

Comment: This will be helpful: `new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);`

Comment: Can some1 provide me an example? :)

Comment: @user1632298: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984719/javascript-fast-parsing-of-yyyy-mm-dd-into-year-month-and-day-numbers

Answer (score 4):

Something like this :

```
    var date = new Date('2013-02-11');        
    /* Add nr of days*/
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

    alert(date.toString());
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Perfect, now i have to find to way to convert date.toString() to yyyy-mm-dd format!

Comment: You can create your own format like this:  var newDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate(); 
    
SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ducwidget/AayZw/)

Answer (score 4):

```
date      = new Date('2013-02-11');
next_date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
```

here's a demo http://jsfiddle.net/MEptb/

Comment: precisely what I was looking for, thank you for the fiddle link

Answer (score 3):

Hope below code will helpful to you

```
function addDays(myDate,days) {
return new Date(myDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}

var myDate = new Date('2013-02-11');

var newDate = addDays(myDate,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function is to Add number of days to today's Date
It returns the Incremented Date in YYYY-MM-DD format
@param noofDays - Specify number of days to increment. 365, for 1 year.

```
function addDaysToCurrentDate(noofDays){
date      = new Date();
next_date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + noofDays));
var IncrementedDate = next_date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
console.log("Incremented Date " +IncrementedDate );
return IncrementedDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the date parameter you can add your required date and you can add days with the `addDays()` function:

```
    var start_date = new Date('2013-02-11');
    var next_date_update = addDays(start_date,1);
    var next_date = new Date(next_date_update).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');

    if(next_date!='Invalid Date')
    {
       var final_date = next_date;
       console.log(final_date);
    }

    function addDays ( myDate , days)
    {
       return new Date(myDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
    }
```

hope it will help you out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).